# How should I use Sqlite "PRAGMA integrity_check" in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I have corrupted database. In commandline I typed

```
PRAGMA integrity_check
```

and sqlite returned

```
On tree page 441 cell 17: Rowid 205 out of order (min less than parent max of 12258)
On tree page 26 cell 12: 2nd reference to page 441
On tree page 26 cell 12: Child page depth differs
On tree page 26 cell 13: Child page depth differs
Page 65 is never used
Page 66 is never used
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_TBL_1
```

In my c program I typed

```
sqlite3 *glbDBHandle;
sqlite3_open(DB_FILE, &glbDBHandle);
int result=sqlite3_exec(glbDBHandle, "PRAGMA integrity_check", 0, 0, 0);
```

this code returns always 0 with broken and healthy databases.

How should I use "PRAGMA integrity_check" in C ? Or how can I know my sqlite database is broken ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) behaves like a SELECT query that returns results in a single row.
To read the results with `sqlite3_exec`, you need to use a callback.

Please note that `PRAGMA integrity_check` is not guaranteed to find all errors, so you can use it only to check for broken databases, not for healthy databases.