# My webpage gives me this error. I have tried many commands but it doesnt work

Tags: jmeter, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I get an error on my website. Can somebody help me. Im not that skilled. I applied a few putty commands and it didnt work.

Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 11, database disk image is malformed in /var/www/html/uadmin/class/user.php on line 89

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on boolean in /var/www/html/uadmin/class/user.php:90 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/uadmin/adm.php(22): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/uadmin/class/user.php on line 90

Answer (score 0):

It seems your database may have become corrupted. [This article](https://sqliteviewer.com/blog/database-disk-image-malformed/) gives some good examples of how that may have happened.
In summary, it might be due to hardware failure or software error. Apparently it sometimes happens when there is a large amount of traffic to your database.

If you don't have a backup of your database, you might have to recreate it from scatch.

Something else you can try is `PRAGMA integrity_check`. That will show you a [little more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172186/how-should-i-use-sqlite-pragma-integrity-check-in-c) info about what might be going on.